# Adding other items in toolbox from dll, do I still need the dll if I give someone the source?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have AjaxControlToolkit.dll , I've added the dll items into my toolbox and I've worked with some items in my asp.net project.

My question is : If I give someone the entire source without the dll located on my desktop , and in my project I used some items from the dll , are they still working(the items) on his pc ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be shown as  missing reference path( with an yellow icon) when someone else opens it. So the best way to handle this is add a folder called "Project Resources /Whatever name you like" under the solution and keep these DLLs there. Add reference from that location. It will be available when you give the soultion files to someone else.

Comment: I've added the dll in resources but how can I add it in toolbox? there's no option to choose resource items.

Comment: I understand but if I've already added some items from it , his job is to add the dll toolbox and everything works perfect?